# Receive full XML from InfoPath task form

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I'm using InfoPath forms as the frontend to my SharePoint workflow tasks. Some of these InfoPath forms have a particularly complex schema (main data source) to the extent that taskChanged_AfterProperties.ExtendedProperties[node/group name] is impractical. I can receive XML fragments of everything contained within a group through ExtendedProperties but I would rather like to receive the entire xml document for the instance of the task form. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to write code that runs inside InfoPath or inside the workflow?

Comment: Inside the workflow. I want to recieve the full infopath xml rather than just node values from it